# Android - Method invocation 'setOnClickListener' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Eu sou novo no Android. O Android Studio sempre me alerta quanto a isso mas não sei o que significa.

```
Method invocation 'setOnClickListener' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

Gostaria de entender melhor do que se trata e qual a lógica para resolver isso. Obrigado.

Aqui está meu snippet do MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Listener Button for Family
        TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);
        family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent familyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FamilyActivity.class);
                startActivity(familyIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Significa que sua Action no TextView pode produzir um erro de valor nulo em tempo de execução caso ela seja inicializada de forma errada.

Muitas pessoas tiveram esse warning utilizando outros componentes como Float Action Button (FAB). Uma forma simples de resolver é verificando antes de definir uma action (como setOnClickListener, por exemplo) se seu textview pode ser nulo.

```
if (family != null) {
 family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent familyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FamilyActivity.class);
            startActivity(familyIntent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Consegui entender melhor agora e vi que o Android Studio sugere essa correção automática através do Lint. Mesmo assim obrigado Antonio!